Does Kellan Lutz portray a Saxon archer in King Arthur (2004)?
In the 2004 film "King Arthur", Arthur & his knights stop at a frozen lake to confront the group of Saxons pursuing them. The lead Saxon (Til Schweiger) calls for one of his archers to measure the range with an arrow. This archer appears to be actor Kellan Lutz, in what would be a very early role (his first acting credit on IMDB is that same year).
Is this Saxon Archer in the frozen lake scene portrayed by Kellan Lutz?

I can provide a screenshot of the actor/character in question if needed, but a similar question about Pan was closed because it had an image... which was weird.

You might get away with the picture here as the person playing the character is unlikely to be on iMDB, Kellan Lutz definitely isn't listed as being in King Arthur. But hey that Pan one was hard to find but was still classed as trivia by some so who knows

Even if you provide an image (and the question could be improved by adding one) it then becomes ID this other actor from an image which is equally off-topic. What proof would be acceptable to you if this was Mr Lutz...other than the image since it woudl come down to opinion otherwise?

@Paulie_D - Well, pretty much anything showing that it was Lutz or NOT Lutz would be acceptable. I guess we'd have to identify who that actor actually was, first. It's basically just an extra, so that might be difficult. I could add a picture of the archer, ask to identify the actor, then remove any references to Kellan Lutz...

I'd add the image...in this case. You have enough specifics to narrow it down but there are no guarantees as to how it will be received. I'm not going to approve or disapprove or vote one way or the other. Leave the reference to Lutz since that's the crux of the question.

I added the picture. No idea if it's Lutz or not, but there are a lot of similarities.

Tentative No
Obviously it isn't on iMdb for a start being an extra but as we know "Absence of evidence is not evidence of absence".
So a bit of deductive reasoning leads me to this conclusion.
King Arthur was released in 2004, the saxon archer looks as follows

In 2004 Kellan Lutz appeared in two shows Model Citizens and The Bold and the Beautiful
Kellan looked like this in Model Citizens:

and a close up

In The Bold and The Beautiful he looked thusly:

Looking at the two side by side
 
We can see that there are similarities between the two noticeably around the eyes, we must admit he was rather baby faced in 2004.
However there are differences too: 

No beard, though this of course could be added as part of make up.
The archers features are more angular and looks older.
The archers nose seems to be more pointed compared to Kellans rounded.
Kellans lips, in particular the bottom half, are fuller.

I would say the archer looks quite like Kellan Lutz now...However the 2004 Kellan Lutz didn't really look that much like him.
Also to show he didn't suddenly age sometime within 2004 between the shows and King Arthur, here is Kellan Lutz in  Stick It ** his first credited feature film, from 2006 
 

Works for me - addresses the similarities, but also gives good reasoning why it's probably not him.
